# Concatenation of arrays

Tags: javascript

How do I parse each index of 3 arrays of string and concatenate each value by same index, to have only one array?

Example input :

```
index 0 of array 1 value : "Car"
index 0 of array 2 value : "red"
index 0 of array 3 value : "Nikolai"
```

Expected output, array (all in one) :

```
index 0 value : "Car , red , Nikolai"
```

Comment: [`Array.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) after iterating through each array and saving its index 0.

Answer (score 3):

For the generic case where you want this concatenation also to happen for index 1, index 2, ...etc, you can use this ES6 function:

```js
function joinTransposed(delim, ...args) {
    return args[0].map( (_, i) => args.map(w => w[i]).join(delim) );
}

// Example
var a = ["c", "y", "s", "h"],
    b = ["a", "o", "e", "i"],
    c = ["n", "u", "e", "m"];

var res = joinTransposed(' , ', a, b, c);
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the arrays in an array, iterate on the arrays and get the first value of it that you will concatenate in a String variable. 
As last add this String variable it in a new array.

```
var arr1 = ['Car', 'red', 'Nikolai'];
var arr2 = ['Car', 'red', 'Nikolai'];
var arr3 = ['Car', 'red', 'Nikolai'];
var arrs = [arr1, arr2, arr3];

var concatenatedString = "";
arrs.forEach(function(arr) {
   if (concatenatedString.length > 0){
     concatenatedString += ", ";
   }
   concatenatedString += arr[0];
});

var result = [concatenatedString];
```

Comment: I think OP has 3 arrays with values in their 0 index and want them pulled into single string separated by commas.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it be possible with a for loop?

```
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    newArray[i] = Array1[i] + "," + Array2[i] + "," + Array3[i]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple for loop. Just mind that the arrays may not be of the same size.

```
var a = ["a", "aa", "aaa"];
var b = ["b", "bb", "bbb"];
var c = ["c", "cc"];

var all = [];

for (var i = 0; i < Math.min(a.length, b.length, c.length); i++) {
    all[i] = [a[i], b[i], c[i]].join(" , ");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With ES6 you can spread array values into a new array. So you could do something like this:

```
const vehicles = ["Car"];
const colors = ["Red"];
const names = ["Nikolai"];

const combined = [...vehicles, ...colors, ...names];
```

Sorry, now I re-read your question you only would like to combine the same index of each array:

```
function returnCombined(index) {
  return [vehicles[index], colors[index], names[index]];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a good case for `.map()` and `.join()`.

```
var result = array.map(a => a[0]).join(", ");
```

---

Or `.reduce()`, though you need to `.slice()` the trailing comma off the result.

```
var result = array.reduce((s,a) => s + a[0] + ", ", "").slice(0, -2);
```